# Can't install code block in my Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

how i install code block in my Ubuntu.when i search in my Ubuntu Application center code block it's shows various applications.i want to install c or c++ editor then tell me which is correct for me.

Comment: Another small IDE for e.g. c++ is `geany`. Also available from the repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and type in,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install codeblocks
```

That will install codeblocks. As for another c++ ide i personally like to use simply `gedit` with a few extensions.